How to increase query_concurrency in AWS Redshift
I am trying to run VACUUM on our cluster. Previously, it used to run fine but since last week I am getting ERROR: 1036 Vacuum column limit exceeded for table account. HINT: increase the value of wlm_query_slot_count or perform a deep copy instead of vacuum.
Currently, wlm_query_slot_count is set as 6. If I increase it to 10 and run VACUUM I am getting ERROR: The query cannot run because wlm_query_slot_count is greater than the query concurrency for the queue. Reduce the slot count to 6 or fewer, and rerun the query. Or, increase the query concurrency if you need more slots.
I've tried searching online but struggling to see how can I increase the query concurrency for the default queue.
To increase the wlm_query_slot_count I am running SET wlm_query_slot_count = 6;. Is there a similar command I can run to increase the query concurrency?

